# What is the name of this graph-theoretic construction?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I have been thinking about a graph-theoretic construction and was wondering if anyone knew what it was called.

I suspect that this is a construction that is

- already named or closely related to a named construction; and
- valid for all directed acyclic graphs (DAGs).

I'll give an example first and then try to formulate the construction.

### Original DAG

[image: Directed acyclic graph (original)]

### Constructed DAG

[image: Directed acyclic graph (after construction)]

### Nonrigorous description of construction

Below is a description of the construction I am asking about.

Given a DAG, the construction (vaguely) consists of

1. possibly adding one or more new vertices (in the example above, the vertex $X$)
2. possibly modifying the edges such that

   1. the constructed graph is still a DAG
   2. reachability and non-reachability between all original vertices are preserved
   3. the underlying undirected graph of the constructed DAG is a tree (unsure about this one — as [@Dániel G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81032/d%c3%a1niel-g) points out, this would be impossible if, say, the subgraph of reachable vertices from some vertex in the original DAG contained a cycle in its underlying graph)

I have not verified that this construction is well-defined (existent/unique) for all DAGs.

The motivation is, in the context where a directed edge from a vertex points to a direct ancestor or a direct dependency, abstracting/inferring "hidden" ancestors or dependencies that "simplify" the overall ancestry or dependence structure.

### Related concepts

Based on my search so far, I suspect these concepts may be related to my construction as (vaguely) described above.

1. [polytree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree)
2. [semilattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice)

Comment: As you note, your question is rather vague. If you only care about reachability, you could take a topological ordering of the vertices, add edges between consecutive vertices and delete the rest of the edges - no need to add new vertices. Then the underlying graph of the resulting digraph is a path. Is this solution satisfactory to you?

Comment: ... Of course, this does not preserve "non-reachability". But you can't do much better: if for vertices $a,b,c,d$ you have that $b,c$ are reachable from $a$ and not reachable from each other, and $d$ is reachable from $b$ and $c$, then the underlying graph will necessarily contain a cycle.

Comment: @Dániel, thanks for the example. It shows straightaway that my proposed constraint for the constructed graph to have a tree as an underlying graph is nonsense. Another perspective is that the way I've described my construction at the moment won't make sense for all DAGs. I came across [multitrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree) before. I could declare multitrees as the type of DAGs which can undergo my construction; this ensures the underlying graph of the subgraph reachable from a vertex contains no cycles.